# getting data element out of li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following:

```
<div class="mCSB_container mCS_no_scrollbar" style="position: relative; left: 0px; width: 195px;">
   <li data-full-image="http://cf.test.com/images/store_logos/original/164df02513c4cfd3235c47a05f05c17005e178cb.jpg" data-large-image="http://cf.test.com/images/store_logos/original/164df02513c4cfd3235c47a05f05c17005e178cb.jpg" class="active">
   <img src="http://cf.test.com/images/store_logos/thumbnail/164df02513c4cfd3235c47a05f05c17005e178cb.jpg" alt="" width="228" height="304">
   </li>
   <li data-full-image="http://cf.test.com/images/store_logos/original/2027539ce2d318d297bb3298f30a433d1b2bae4a.jpg" data-large-image="http://cf.test.com/images/store_logos/original/2027539ce2d318d297bb3298f30a433d1b2bae4a.jpg" class="">
   <img src="http://cf.test.com/images/store_logos/thumbnail/2027539ce2d318d297bb3298f30a433d1b2bae4a.jpg" alt="" width="228" height="304">
   </li>
</div>
```

I tried doing:

```
$('.mCSB_container').children('li').each(function () {
    console.log(this.data("data-full-image"));
});
```

but then it says it doesn't have a method data in it. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` is a jQuery method so you need to wrap `this` in jQuery otherwise you're just referring to the DOM element, which doesn't have a `data` method:

```
$(this).data("data-full-image")
```

Answer (score 1):

`.data()` is a jQuery method, so give `this` a jquery wrapper:

```
$(this).data('full-image');
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap this in jQuery $(this)

```
$('.mCSB_container').children('li').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).data("full-image"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ccTdd/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
$('.mCSB_container').children('li').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).data("fullImage"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also do this

```
$('.mCSB_container').children('li').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).attr("data-full-image"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 alert( $('.mCSB_container li').data('full-image'))
})
```